# How to keep sources locally when using 'Linux development with C++' in VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cross-platform

I have some sources that I intend to compile/debug for Windows/Linux and other platforms in the future.

So far it runs on Windows so I installed the 'Linux development with C++' package in VisualStudio to compile/debug it for Linux.

I tried a small example that worked but it uploads the sources prior to compilation and that is not what I want.

I would like to compile the sources locally on my Windows PC (using LLVM) instead of having VisualStudio copying source files to a linux vm/server for remote compiling.

I prefer having the sources only in one 'secured' location, and keeping everything locally like the compiler(s) and the linux system file headers.  So my main reasons for not uploading the sources is security and also source control.

So VisualStudio would compile locally (using LLVM) and then upload the executable on the linux vm/server and run it for a debugging.  Or if the executable is already present or running, it could just launch it or attach to the process for a remote debugging session.

I am not sure if this is possible. All the examples I saw assumed that the sources were on the linux target.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work. The Linux VM is not just for running/debugging, but also for building — technically you could cross-compile but it's far more complicated and the feature designers have opted not to do that.

[It is possible to turn off the copying of sources](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/), *but only if you're already copying/syncing them by other means*:

> The Copy Sources property page allows you to specify whether to copy sources to the remote Linux system. You may not want to copy sources if you are working with a share or are managing your own synchronization through other means.

If you cannot secure the VM or the path between it and your primary development environment, you should switch to a fully enclosed, Linux-based development environment.

Comment: I can't imagine running/debugging requires remote sources, but the feature has been designed such that _building_ takes place remotely, and _building_ requires sources. So they're already up there before you run/debug.

Comment: Switching to Linux-based development environment is not a solution for me.  I am wondering about 3 things: 1- If the executable is present on the target Linux, would running/debugging remote be possible or does it need the sources on the target for the debugging?  2- If this is technically possible, why are you saying that it's not going to work.  I am thinking that since VS already has the ability to copy files, it could copy the executable only.  And the executable can be cross-compiled using LLVM.  3- Could you clarify where you saw that the feature designers have opted not to do that?

Comment: I don't follow you. The fact that you had to ask this question is how we know the feature designers have opted not do to that. It didn't just happen by accident.

Comment: Well I thought you might have read that somewhere.  In any case, just because it was not supported intentionally when they released the feature does not mean it is not possible.